# Using SSL with Wininet

Tags: c, windows, winapi, ssl, https

Someone can give me example how to use SSL with wininet API's ?
Here is my code but no success.....

```
DWORD dwFlags = INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE|INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID|SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA|INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID|INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTO_REDIRECT|INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE|INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE;

hOpen = InternetOpen(UserAgent,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,NULL,NULL,0);
hConnect = InternetConnect(hOpen,Url,INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT,NULL,NULL,INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP,0,0);
hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect,GET,Pages,NULL,NULL,NULL,dwFlags,0);

HttpSendRequest(hRequest,ContentType,-1L,NULL,0);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For sites that use valid certificates, you shouldn't have to do anything special, other than specifying the https URL, of course. For self-generated certificates you may need to manually install the certificate authority on the client machine, and/or provide some of the IGNORE flags.

A great way to troubleshoot issues like this is to install a WININET callback. This lets you monitor the progress that WININET is making (or not) while communicating.

There's an example (that I haven't personally used) of how to use it here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25185/WinINet-Test-Application

Comment: When i run my code i launch sniffer and seems that only the certificate is download.... and yes i use self-generated certificate. With these ignore flags it had to run but no....